# Showing pictures on a map based on the location they were taken in the Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

Is it possible in Google Photos to view the photos overlayed on a map that shows the location where they were taken?

I frequently find that I want to find a picture taken at my cabin which is in the middle of nowhere and therefore Google doesn't automatically create a location name for it in the location list.

If I could just zoom in on a map, I would have no trouble filtering it down.  For example, Google Photos for Android's [Map View supports this](https://www.makeuseof.com/map-view-google-photos-see-images-on-map/).

Is there a similar option in the web application?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Google Photos web application doesn't include that functionality however you can achieve something similar using [Google My Maps](https://mymaps.google.com/)

It requires creating a custom map and and choosing the photos that should be included from Google Photos.

If you want photos automatically added to the map as you add them to Google photos you would need to use a Google Apps Script project or find a third party script that dopes the same.

The basic approach:

1. Navigate to [Google My Maps](https://mymaps.google.com/)
2. Select [image: CREATE A NEW MAP].
3. In the **Untilted map** dialog that appears, select [image: Import].
4. In the **Choose a file to import** dialog select [image: Albums]
5. Choose an album, select photos you would like added, then [image: Insert]
6. Repeat steps 3 - 5 for any additional albums.

Note you can also view the custom map in Google Earth.

1. Navigate to [Google My Maps](https://mymaps.google.com/)
2. Open the custom map by clicking on it.
3. In the [image: kebab] menu next to the map title, select [image: View in Google Earth]